# elastic transport_request is more than limit

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

We having 7.2 elastic cluster with below node.
6 Data node 
3 MAster Node
2 ingest node

Recently we observed below error in our elastic logs. 
seems like default limit is [986061209/940.3mb], but real usage([990145976/944.2mb]) is more than that. Please let us know is there any configuration to increase transport_request size above 986061209.

[2020-02-04T00:37:24,464][DEBUG][o.e.a.a.c.n.i.TransportNodesInfoAction] [blp06742225] failed to execute on node [64OKIQjOQ6WaVWNQgW-lTQ]
org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: [blp06742240][10.52.54.95:61025][cluster:monitor/nodes/info[n]]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.common.breaker.CircuitBreakingException: [parent] Data too large, data for [] would be [990152526/944.2mb], which is larger than the limit of [986061209/940.3mb], real usage: [990145976/944.2mb], new bytes reserved: [6550/6.3kb]
        at org.elasticsearch.indices.breaker.HierarchyCircuitBreakerService.checkParentLimit(HierarchyCircuitBreakerService.java:343) ~[elasticsearch-7.2.1.jar:7.2.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.breaker.ChildMemoryCircuitBreaker.addEstimateBytesAndMaybeBreak(ChildMemoryCircuitBreaker.java:128) ~[elasticsearch-7.2.1.jar:7.2.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.InboundHandler.handleRequest(InboundHandler.java:173) [elasticsearch-7.2.1.jar:7.2.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.InboundHandler.messageReceived(InboundHandler.java:121) [elasticsearch-7.2.1.jar:7.2.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.InboundHandler.inboundMessage(InboundHandler.java:105) [elasticsearch-7.2.1.jar:7.2.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.inboundMessage(TcpTransport.java:660) [elasticsearch-7.2.1.jar:7.2.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4MessageChannelHandler.channelRead(Netty4MessageChannelHandler.java:62) [transport-netty4-client-7.2.1.jar:7.2.1]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) [netty-transport-4.1.35.Final.jar:4.1.35.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) [netty-transport-4.1.35.Final.jar:4.1.35.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352) [netty-transport-4.1.35.Final.jar:4.1.35.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:323) [netty-codec-4.1.35.Final.jar:4.1.35.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:297) [netty-codec-4.1.35.Final.jar:4.1.35.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) [netty-transport-4.1.35.Final.jar:4.1.35.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) [netty-transport-4.1.35.Final.jar:4.1.35.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352) [netty-transport-4.1.35.Final.jar:4.1.35.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler.channelRead(LoggingHandler.java:241) [netty-handler-4.1.35.Final.jar:4.1.35.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) [netty-transport-4.1.35.Final.jar:4.1.35.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) [netty-transport-4.1.35.Final.jar:4.1.35.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352) [netty-transport-4.1.35.Final.jar:4.1.35.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1408) [netty-transport-4.1.35.Final.jar:4.1.35.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) [netty-transport-4.1.35.Final.jar:4.1.35.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) [netty-transport-4.1.35.Final.jar:4.1.35.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:930) [netty-transport-4.1.35.Final.jar:4.1.35.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163) [netty-transport-4.1.35.Final.jar:4.1.35.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:682) [netty-transport-4.1.35.Final.jar:4.1.35.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioEventLoop.java:582) [netty-transport-4.1.35.Final.jar:4.1.35.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:536) [netty-transport-4.1.35.Final.jar:4.1.35.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496) [netty-transport-4.1.35.Final.jar:4.1.35.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:906) [netty-common-4.1.35.Final.jar:4.1.35.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) [netty-common-4.1.35.Final.jar:4.1.35.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835) [?:?]

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the heap of the node is pretty full and being caught by the circuit breaker what is nice because it prevents the nodes from running into OOMs, going stale and crash...

Elasticsearch 6.2.0 introduced the circuit breaker and improved it in 7.0.0.

One of the nodes `(64OKIQjOQ6WaVWNQgW-lTQ)` has been requested by another node to execute a search or (bulk) index action on his shards but failed due to low memory. This is exactly the case here according to this error message:

```
Data too large, data for [] would be [990152526/944.2mb], which is larger than the limit of [986061209/940.3mb], real usage: [990145976/944.2mb], new bytes reserved: [6550/6.3kb]
```

Also note the name of involved Classes and Methods in the Stackrace:

org.elasticsearch.common.breaker.**ChildMemoryCircuitBreaker**.**addEstimateBytesAndMaybeBreak**(ChildMemoryCircuitBreaker.java:128)

If you can't increase heap or reduce the data held by the nodes, you need to scale up your cluster.

Here are some background informations:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/circuit-breaker.html

https://www.elastic.co/blog/improving-node-resiliency-with-the-real-memory-circuit-breaker

If you need a fast solution, try increasing the circuit breaker limits using the api described in the docs. But keep in mind, that this does not solve the problem at all.